# SvelteKit TypeError: URL is not a constructor

Tags: typescript, svelte, sveltekit

Im continiously running into this issue with @sveltejs/kit, URL is not used or referenced in my code. Im getting this error both in the bundled code after build as well as during development, i have tried with different adapters, but that does not seem to do anything. I'm experiencing this issue both with yarn and npm, and before and after build. Anyone have any idea on how to solve this?

```
Listening on port 3000
file:///app/index.js:15823
            const parsed = new URL(req.url || '', 'http://localhost');
                           ^

TypeError: URL is not a constructor
    at Array.<anonymous> (file:///app/index.js:15823:19)
    at loop (file:///app/index.js:13738:58)
    at next (file:///app/index.js:13739:69)
    at Array.noop_handler (file:///app/index.js:15794:44)
    at loop (file:///app/index.js:13738:58)
    at next (file:///app/index.js:13739:69)
    at Array.<anonymous> (file:///app/index.js:14022:28)
    at loop (file:///app/index.js:13738:58)
    at next (file:///app/index.js:13739:69)
    at Array.compression (file:///app/index.js:13463:5)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

> The result above is from a node docker image, ran with node.

Logging URL just before the error returns:

```
{
  createObjectURL: [Function: createObjectURL],
  revokeObjectURL: [Function: revokeObjectURL]
}
Error: TypeError: URL is not a constructor
```

Node version: 16.1.0

Response from a simple post:

```
Error: TypeError: URL is not a constructor
Body: {}
Error
    at eval (/src/lib/ft4/auth.ts:15:11)
    at async Object.handle (//Users/indico/Projects/Web-Recorder/src/hooks.ts:22:54)
    at async respond (file:///Users/indico/Projects/Web-Recorder/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/dist/ssr.js:1510:10)
    at async Immediate.<anonymous> (file:///Users/indico/Projects/Web-Recorder/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/dist/chunks/index.js:3305:23)
{ user: undefined, accessToken: '7euwpophib4h3wai76cr1bpnrhkldobw' } get_task
{
  createObjectURL: [Function: createObjectURL],
  revokeObjectURL: [Function: revokeObjectURL]
}
Error: TypeError: URL is not a constructor
Body: {"action":"get_task","task_id":"078E57F7-7161-45AD-B00E-0CEDD3C4E19B","include":"full"}
Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at hash (file:///Users/indico/Projects/Web-Recorder/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/dist/ssr.js:286:16)
    at render (file:///Users/indico/Projects/Web-Recorder/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/dist/ssr.js:1543:26)
    at async Object.handle (/Users/indico/Projects/Web-Recorder/src/hooks/index.ts:35:25)
    at async respond (file:///Users/indico/Projects/Web-Recorder/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/dist/ssr.js:1510:10)
    at async Immediate.<anonymous> (file:///Users/indico/Projects/Web-Recorder/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/dist/chunks/index.js:3305:23)
```

tsconfig:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "module": "ES2020",
    "lib": [
      "ES2020",
      "DOM",
      "DOM.Iterable"
    ],
    "target": "ES2020",
    /**
      svelte-preprocess cannot figure out whether you have a value or a type, so tell TypeScript
      to enforce using \`import type\` instead of \`import\` for Types.
      */
    "importsNotUsedAsValues": "error",
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    /**
      To have warnings/errors of the Svelte compiler at the correct position,
      enable source maps by default.
      */
    "sourceMap": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "allowJs": true,
    "checkJs": true,
    "paths": {
      "$app/*": [
        ".svelte/dev/runtime/app/*",
        ".svelte/build/runtime/app/*"
      ],
      "$service-worker": [
        ".svelte/build/runtime/service-worker"
      ],
      "$lib/*": [
        "src/lib/*"
      ],
      "$icons/*": [
        "src/lib/icons/*"
      ],
      "$comp/*": [
        "src/lib/components/*"
      ],
      "package.json": [
        "./package.json"
      ],
      "$src/*": [
        "src/*"
      ]
    }
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.d.ts",
    "src/**/*.js",
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "src/**/*.svelte",
    "types/**/*"
  ]
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "main": "index.js",
  "private": true,
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "svelte-kit dev",
    "build": "svelte-kit build --verbose",
    "start": "svelte-kit start",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@sveltejs/adapter-node": "^1.0.0-next.9",
    "@sveltejs/adapter-static": "^1.0.0-next.9",
    "@types/cookie": "^0.4.0",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.168",
    "@types/node": "^15.3.0",
    "@types/recordrtc": "^5.6.5",
    "@types/uuid": "^8.3.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.19.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.19.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.2.5",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "cssnano": "^4.1.10",
    "eslint": "^7.22.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-svelte3": "^3.2.0",
    "postcss": "^8.2.15",
    "postcss-load-config": "^3.0.1",
    "postcss-nested": "^5.0.5",
    "prettier": "~2.3.0",
    "prettier-plugin-svelte": "^2.2.0",
    "simplytyped": "^3.3.0",
    "svelte": "^3.38.2",
    "svelte-preprocess": "^4.7.3",
    "tailwindcss": "^2.1.0",
    "tslib": "^2.2.0",
    "typescript": "^4.0.0",
    "vite": "^2.3.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@sveltejs/kit": "^1.0.0-next.107",
    "@tailwindcss/aspect-ratio": "^0.2.0",
    "@tailwindcss/custom-forms": "^0.2.1",
    "@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.3.2",
    "@tailwindcss/line-clamp": "^0.2.0",
    "@tailwindcss/typography": "^0.4.0",
    "cookie": "^0.4.1",
    "date-fns": "^2.21.3",
    "filesize.js": "^2.0.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "recordrtc": "^5.6.2",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2"
  },
  "type": "module",
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=16.0.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Is that a file you created? Try adding `import { URL } from 'url'` to your app/index.js.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having removed dependencies one by one, it seems that *recordrtc* causes window.URL to loose its constructor. Removing this resolved the problem.

Answer (score -1):

One thing that can cause this the fact that you declared your dependencies as dependencies instead of devDependencies. From your package.json, you are using svelte-kit and remember that sveltekit uses SSR and it will bundle all your devDependencies before runtime.

It is important that if the dependency is used server-side, you must put it as devDependency, but if it's used client side, you can put it in normal deps. I prefer to put everything inside devDependency to make sure that SvelteKit can render everything in the server. Here's a SO answer that explains a little more about it: [Should a svelte package be a dependency or a devDependency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68190803/should-a-svelte-package-be-a-dependency-or-a-devdependency/69002933#69002933)

Comment: I see what you mean, but why even post this? This is not an answer nor even a touch on the issue, just you letting us know that you know what `devDependencies` are... It should as per your own explanation be in dependencies, so again, why post this?