# Should a svelte package be a dependency or a devDependency?

Tags: javascript, npm, dependency-management, svelte

I know that there are already a lot of posts concerning the distinction between `dependency` and `devDependency` but I didn't find any that explain it for the case of svelte so lets open this one here.

In most of the svelte package like [svelte-material-ui](https://github.com/hperrin/svelte-material-ui) or [svelte-routing](https://github.com/EmilTholin/svelte-routing), the installation guide tell to install the package as a `dependency`. However since svelte will compile this package during the build time, the new library that will use it doesn't need to install this svelte package. So I don't see why it has to be a `dependency`.

Maybe this question is opinion based but would be nice to have at least a small idea of what to use.

Answer (score 13):

In SvelteKit (the next version of Sapper) there is one major difference between `dependency` and `devDependency`: any module used in a (server-side) [endpoint](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs#routing-endpoints) must be a `dependency`. If not, the project may not work when deployed on a serverless platform, although it will work locally.

Otherwise, I prefer to keep everything as a `devDependency`. I think it makes sense because Svelte is a compiler, and the packages are only needed at compile-time. However, I don't think it would hurt to just put everything as a `dependency`.

Comment: Source for this would be nice. Not that I doubt it, just want to learn more

Comment: @BrunoEly: This issue often comes up in the SvelteKit discord chat. Also it makes sense if you think about the way serverless functions work.

Answer (score 11):

I believe this is personal opinion.  If you're not distributing your code as an NPM package, the distinction should be minimal.  See, for example, [this related discussion](https://github.com/ItalyPaleAle/svelte-spa-router/issues/10).

In my experience with web projects, it's helpful to distinguish between dependencies that are used for building/testing (devDependencies) vs. those that are "used at runtime" (dependencies).  You're right that, with Svelte, none of the literal code is used at runtime, but then everything would be a devDependency, so you don't get a useful separation.

[The NPM documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/specifying-dependencies-and-devdependencies-in-a-package-json-file) says that the distinction should be production vs. development/testing.